# React. Can't acces API data on local 5000. Database from CSV file. Promise undefined response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I've been going crazy for a couple of days with an unresolved issue. Please help.

Working with a CSV database here. Creating own API. Small React App Fullstack MERN.

I'm trying to get to show all the employeees from my database.

I wrote the backend with express and have all the data now showing in json format on localhost:5000/employees

Also created a context on the front to deal with that data and reducer file for the functions.

Problem I have is I'm not beeing able to use the data on the ContextProvider file. ('EmployeesState')
Promise of my async function keeps giving me an undefined response. Tried both with fetch and axios but is not working.

Some of the code is from a previous project i did and it worked there so i 'm going crazy here. I can't seem to solve it. Please help.

BACKEND

db.js

```
const parse = require("csv-parse");
const fs = require("fs");

const employeesData = [];

const connectDB = () => {
  fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/employees1.txt")
    .pipe(
      parse({
        delimiter: ",",
        columns: true,
      })
    )
    .on("data", (dataRow) => {
      employeesData.push(dataRow);
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log(employeesData);
    });
};

connectDB();
// console.log(connectDB());

module.exports = connectDB;
module.exports = employeesData;
```

server.js

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");

const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const employeesData = require("./config/db");
var path = require("path");
var app = express();

// const config = require("config");

//Connect DB
// connectDB();

let dataBase = employeesData;
console.log(employeesData);

app.use(cors());
// app.use(bodyParser.json()); //here
// Initial Middleware
//By doing this we can accepta data. Using the req.body
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

///Define Routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/employees", require("./routes/employees"));

//Serve React in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //Set static folder (build folder)
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  );
}
// app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);
app.set("view engine", "html");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

employees.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const config = require("config");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const Employee = require("../models/EmployeeModel");
const employeesData = require("../config/db");

// router.get("/", function (req, res) {
//   res.send({ employeesData });
// });
//@route    GET  api/employees
//@desc     Get all users Employees
//@access   Private
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employees = await employeesData;
    res.json({ employees });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});

//@route    POST  api/employees
//@desc     Add new Employee
//@access   Private
router.post(
  "/",
  [
    check("name", "Name is required").not().isEmpty(),
    check("surname", "Surname is required").not().isEmpty(),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { name, surname, adress, phone, email, birthdate } = req.body;

    try {
      const newEmployee = new Employee({
        name,
        surname,
        adress,
        phone,
        email,
        birthdate,
      });

      const employee = await newEmployee.save();

      res.json(employee);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);

//@route    DELETE  api/employee
//@desc     Delete Employee

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let employee = await Employee.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!employee) return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Employee not found" });

    await Employee.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);

    res.json({ msg: `Employee removed` });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

FRONTEND

EmployeesState.js

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import EmployeesContext from "./employeesContext";
import employeesReducer from "./employeesReducer";
import {
  ADD_EMPLOYEE,
  DELETE_EMPLOYEE,
  SET_CURRENT,
  CLEAR_CURRENT,
  UPDATE_EMPLOYEE,
  FILTER_EMPLOYEES,
  EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
  CLEAR_FILTER,
  GET_EMPLOYEES,
  CLEAR_EMPLOYEES,
} from "../types";

const EmployeesState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    employees: [],
    current: null,
    filtered: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(employeesReducer, initialState);
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState(initialState);

  //Get Employees

  // // gives me promise{<prending>} on console
  const getEmployees = async () => {
    try {
      const res = axios.get("http://localhost:5000/employees");
      dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYEES, payload: res });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
      });
    }
  };

  //trying with fetch. throwing me undefined on console
  const callAPI = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/employees")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) =>
        setEmployees({
          ...initialState,
          loading: false,
          employees: res,
        })
      );
  };

  //Add Employee
  const addEmployee = async (employee) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/employees", employee, config);
      dispatch({ type: ADD_EMPLOYEE, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.data.msg,
      });
    }
  };

  //Delete Employee
  const deleteEmployee = async (id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/employees/${id}`);

      dispatch({ type: DELETE_EMPLOYEE, payload: id });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.msg,
      });
    }
  };

  //Update Employee
  const updateEmployee = async (employee) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.put(
        `/api/employees/${employee._id}`,
        employee,
        config
      );
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_EMPLOYEE, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.msg,
      });
    }

    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_EMPLOYEE, payload: employee });
  };

  //Clear Employees
  const clearEmployees = () => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_EMPLOYEES });
  };

  //Set Current Employees
  const setCurrent = (employee) => {
    dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT, payload: employee });
  };

  //Clear Current Employee
  const clearCurrent = () => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_CURRENT });
  };

  //Filter Employees
  const filterEmployees = (text) => {
    dispatch({ type: FILTER_EMPLOYEES, payload: text });
  };

  //Clear Filter
  const clearFilter = (text) => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_FILTER });
  };

  return (
    <EmployeesContext.Provider
      value={{
        employees: state.employees,
        current: state.current,
        filtered: state.filtered,
        error: state.error,
        loading: state.loading,
        callAPI,
        getEmployees,
        addEmployee,
        deleteEmployee,
        clearEmployees,
        setCurrent,
        clearCurrent,
        updateEmployee,
        filterEmployees,
        clearFilter,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </EmployeesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default EmployeesState;

// // gives me undefined on console
// const getEmployees = () => {
//   axios
//     .get("http://localhost:5000/employees")
//     .then((res) => dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYEES, payload: res }))
//     .catch((err) => {
//       dispatch({
//         type: EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
//       });
//     });
// };
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Search from "../employees/Search";
import Employees from "../employees/Employees";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Search />
      <Employees />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Employees.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import EmployeeItem from "./EmployeeItem";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import EmployeesContext from "../../contexts/employees/employeesContext";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";

const Employees = () => {
  const employeesContext = useContext(EmployeesContext);

  const {
    employees,
    filtered,
    getEmployees,
    callAPI,
    loading,
  } = employeesContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    // callAPI();
    getEmployees();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(employees);
    console.log(getEmployees());
    console.log(callAPI());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <>
        {[employees].map((employee) => (
          <EmployeeItem key={uuidv4()} employee={employee} />
        ))}
      </>
    </div>
  );
```

employeesReducer.js

```
import {
  GET_EMPLOYEES,
  ADD_EMPLOYEE,
  DELETE_EMPLOYEE,
  SET_CURRENT,
  CLEAR_CURRENT,
  UPDATE_EMPLOYEE,
  FILTER_EMPLOYEES,
  CLEAR_FILTER,
  EMPLOYEE_ERROR,
  CLEAR_EMPLOYEES,
} from "../types";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_EMPLOYEES:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case ADD_EMPLOYEE:
      return {
        ...state,
        employee: [action.payload, ...state.employees],
        loading: false,
      };
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: state.employees.map((employee) =>
          employee._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : employee
        ),
        loading: false,
      };

    case DELETE_EMPLOYEE:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: state.employees.filter(
          (employee) => employee._id !== action.payload
        ),
        loading: false,
      };
    case CLEAR_EMPLOYEES:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: null,
        filtered: null,
        error: null,
        current: null,
      };
    case SET_CURRENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_CURRENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: null,
      };
    case FILTER_EMPLOYEES:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtered: state.employees.filter((employee) => {
          const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, "gi");
          return employee.name.match(regex) || employee.email.match(regex);
        }),
      };
    case CLEAR_FILTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtered: null,
      };
    case EMPLOYEE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await for the response

```
const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/employees");
dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYEES, payload: res });
```

or

```
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/employees")
.then(res => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYEES, payload: res });
})
```

Comment: Thank for response. Still not working. I can see the data on my http://localhost:5000/   but i can;t acces it still. Also tried fetch

Comment: Try to put a `console.log(res)` before the dispatch and post the result.

Comment: Link to screenshots https://imgur.com/a/VQ93iRL?    I'm getting the response and the object with the data on the response but I don;t know why I'm not processing it correctly in the dispatch or something. Thanks again.

Comment: Because you need to send `res.data` in your payload to the dispatch

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time. I'm getting the data on the console. But not beeing able to display it.

Comment: return (
    <div>
      <>
        {[employees].map((employee) => (
          <ul key={uuidv4()}>
            <li>
              {employee.name} {employee.surname}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </>
      {/* <p>{employees[0].name}</p> */}
    </div>
  );             res.data is an object which has an 'employees' key with an array inside.

Comment: Thanks so much again bro. I solved it. Was a silly typo mistake for not displaying.